# python-docx detect enumerated list

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

i would like to detect enumerated list in a word document using python-docx. like

```
if paragraph is enum:
  #do something
```

Is it possible in python-docx?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the style of paragraph:

```
if paragraph.style.name == 'List Paragraph':
    #do something
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be an incomplete answer, but most of the enums or numbered lists have numbering properties reference (`w:numPr`) property within paragraph properties (`w:pPr`).

This code is listing all paragraphs which contain `w:numPr` within `w:pPr`:

```
[p for p in doc.paragraphs if len(p._element.xpath('./w:pPr/w:numPr')) > 0]
```

Hope this helps,

Best

Answer (score 0):

I have a fork of python-docx ([bayoo-docx](https://pypi.org/project/bayoo-docx/))
which I implemented listed related features into it

```
list_paragraph = [for paragraph in document.paragraphs if paragraph.list_info[0]]
```

*paragraph.list_info* returns a tuple (bool paragraph or not, num id of the list, level of the list item)